# Redirecting to a node template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm pretty new to node and everything that happens around, but I'm trying to make a little admin panel. There will be a login page and after login if the user is an admin the page will redirect to `dashboard.ejs`.
I suppose I didn't do it the correct way because what I did don't work.
Let me show you what I did :

Let's start with my main routes for admin. So these can be accesses with `/admin` and `/admin/dashboard`. If I just go to `/admin` the page loads normally with the login forms.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('../views/admin/admin.ejs')
})

router.get('/dashboard', admin_check, (req, res) => {
  res.render('../views/admin/dashboard.ejs')
  console.log('dashboard rendered...')
})
```

I have a simple login button that will do some checks in the database and finally run this to redirect to the dashboard :

```
fetch('/admin/dashboard', {
    headers: {
       auth_token: sessionStorage.getItem('token')
    }
})
```

This will correctly trigger and let the `console.log()` run that comes from here :

```
router.get('/dashboard', admin_check, (req, res) => {
  res.render('../views/admin/dashboard.ejs')
  console.log('dashboard rendered...')
})
```

The thing is, the dashboard isn't loaded while the `res.render()` in fact executed.

There is an error in console though : 
`The resource from “http://localhost:8080/admin/scripts/admin-auth.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`

I looked up a little bit what this was but I don't really understand anything about it.

Here is my full `admin-auth.js` file :

```
$('#login_form').submit(e => {
  e.preventDefault()

  fetch('/api/user/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email: $('#login_email').val(),
      password: $('#login_password').val()
    })
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.status === 200) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
        sessionStorage.setItem('user', data.user)
        fetch('/api/user', {
          headers: {
            auth_token: data.token
          }
        })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(data => {
            if (data.user.admin) {
              fetch('/admin/dashboard', {
                headers: {
                  auth_token: sessionStorage.getItem('token')
                }
              })
            }
          })
      } else {
        console.log(data.error)
      }
    })
})
```

EDIT: So I used this instead  :

```
res.sendFile(process.cwd() + '/src/views/admin/dashboard.ejs')
```

But the page still don't appear. Errors are gone and in the network management I get a 200 response but that's it

Comment: can u specify what is the node router code for the `/admin/dashboard`?

Comment: In my `app.js` I have this : `app.use('/admin', adminRoutes)`, adminRoutes is the file with the 2 routes / and /dashboard above. Is it that what you need?

Comment: cool, yes , so i see that the response of the 'fetch` that makes the call to `/admin/dashboard` for which the response is an `ejs` template, could u pass the `'Content-Type': 'text/html',` along with that fetch headers
and change it to `res.sendFile` instead of `render`

Comment: I've added the Content-Type and used `res.sendFile` instead but it it still don't show the page. I get an error in the network tools of firefox when he tries to access that : `path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`

Comment: I've seen that I can use `__dirname` but how do I use it in this case? The view file are not in the same directory as the routes

Comment: `var path = require('path')` then use it as , `res.sendFile( path.resolve('./src/views/admin/dashboard.ejs'))`